# Tracking changes in web application

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I have an application in which the user needs to see the changes that have been made during the latest edit.
By changes I mean, the changes made in all inputs like a textarea, dropdowns.

I am trying to implement this by showing a background image on the right top and then when the user clicks this background image, a popup is shown which shows the difference.
I am using prototype 1.7.0.

My First question would be:-
     1. What would be the best approach to implement this functionality?
      2. Can I put a onClick on the background image?

Comment: Changes that have been made to what? A page, a textarea, a form an image?

Comment: I don't know why someone should downvote this question without leaving  comment as to why this question is downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

There some functions in the jQuery library that I believe would be helpful to you.  If you are using prototype, I would guess that there is some similar functionality you may utilize.

I would suggest writing some code like this:

```
var $input = $('input').add('textarea').add('select');

$input.each(function() {
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 var value = $(this).val();
 var hiddenId = 'hidden' + id;
 var newHiddenInput = $("<input type='hidden'").val(value).attr('id',hiddenId);
 $(this).after(newHiddenInput);
});
```

The above code will create a new hidden input for each input, textarea, and select on your page.  It will have the same value as the input it duplicates.  It will have an id equivalent to prepending the id with the word 'hidden'.

I don't know if you can attach a click handler to a background image.  If your inputs are enclosed inside a `<div>`, you may be able to get the result you want by attaching the click handler to your div.

In any case, you should now have the old values where you can easily compare them to the user's input so that you can prepare a summary of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype gives us the [`Hash`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Hash/) class which is almost perfect for this but lacks a way of calculating the difference with another hash, so let's add that...

```
Hash.prototype.difference = function(hash)
{
    var result = this.clone();
    hash.each(function(pair) {
        if (result.get(pair.key) === undefined)
            // exists in hash but not in this
            result.set(pair.key, pair.value);
        else if (result.get(pair.key) == pair.value)
            // no difference so remove from result
            result.unset(pair.key);
        // else exists in this but not in hash
    });
    return result;
};
```

This is no way to tell if an element was clicked on just it's background image - you can find out the coordinates where it was clicked but that is not foolproof, especially since CSS3 adds complications like multiple backgrounds and transitions. It is better to have an absolutely positioned element to act as a button.

```
$('button-element').observe('click', function() {
    var form_values = $H($('form-id').serialize(true));
    if (old_values) {
        var differences = old_values.difference(form_values);
        if (differences.size()) {
            showDiffPopup(differences);
        }
    }
    window.old_values = form_values;
});
// preset current values in advance
window.old_values = $H($('form-id').serialize(true));
```

All that remains is to implement `showDiffPopup` to show the calculated `differences`.